# Optimal distance with dynamic programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

Okay, so honestly this is a homework question, but I really did my best to find the solution, and I think I partially did.

The question:

We are given a series of cities whose positions are symbolized with only one coordinate and we are supposed to implement a given number of hospitals to cities so that the sum of each cities' distance to nearest hospital will be minimum.

That is, if we are given the cities at 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 and if we are going to put 3 hospitals, the hospitals will be at 3, 7, 11 (actually there could be multiple best solutions for this one, did not check).

We are advised to use dynamic programming and first check the case in which we implement only one hospital.

I've figured out finding the subsequent hospital's location. I create a table, and of cities. Then to each cell, I put either the city of the current rows' distance to closest hospital that already build or city's distance to city of the corresponding column.

For example, if we already implemented a hospital to 1, it would be like:

*-1-3-5-7-9-11-13

1|0|0|0|0|0|0||0|

3|2|0|2|2|2|2|2|

5|4|2|0|2|4|4|4|

..............

then sum the columns and find the next hospital.

The problem is, I cannot figure out the first hospital that I'm supposed to build!!

When I manually add one of the element of the actual solution, I can get the right answer so my partial solution should be true.

BTW complexity should be O(CityNum^2), hospitalNum is a constant. So I can't use bruteforce.

An example input and output (from the homework assg):

Input:
10 5 (10 is city num, 5 is hospital num)

1 2 3 6 7 9 11 22 44 50 (coordinates)

Output:

9 (sum of minimum distances)

Comment: Props on being up-front about it being a homework question. Personally I think it's ok as long as you learn from the answer enough to be able to perform up to the specification the exam certifies you once you have passed, but I will see if there's a question in meta and if not raise one... :/)

Comment: One approach: Add up the distances between cities, divide by number of hospitals, place the hospital at the closest city that fits that average distance. Continue from there.

Comment: a solution using `dp` of complexity `O(cityNum ^ 3)` is possible, i do not know whether that complexity could be reduced using some pre-computations.